# After timeout, SIGBART RKRequestQueue " Attempted to decrement loading count below zero

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5, restkit

I get the following error, what can I do?

2012-02-02 16:12:15.873 iPadAlertPrototype[16574:fb03] *** Terminating
app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException',
reason: 'Attempted to decrement loading count below zero'

First Class

```
+(void)loadTaskGroups
 {
    [[RKObjectManager sharedManager].requestQueue
    setConcurrentRequestsLimit:1];
     [[RKObjectManager sharedManager].requestQueue setDelegate:self];
     [[RKObjectManager sharedManager].requestQueue
    setShowsNetworkActivityIndicatorWhenBusy:YES];

     RKObjectLoader* loader = [[RKObjectManager sharedManager]

     objectLoaderWithResourcePath:TASKGROUPURL delegate:self];
     loader.backgroundPolicy = RKRequestBackgroundPolicyRequeue;
     [loader sendSynchronously];
     [loader  setTimeoutInterval:60];
     [loader setBackgroundPolicy:RKRequestBackgroundPolicyRequeue];
     [[RKObjectManager sharedManager].requestQueue  addRequest:loader];
     [[RKObjectManager sharedManager].requestQueue start];
} 
-(void)objectLoaderDidFinishLoading:(RKObjectLoader *)objectLoader
{
  [TaskGroup loadTasks];
}
```

TaskGroup Class

```
+ (void)loadTasks
{
 for (TaskGroup *taskGroup in  [TaskGroup allObjects])
 {
   if ([[taskGroup class]isSubclassOfClass:[TaskGroup class]])
   {
     RKObjectLoader* loader = [[RKObjectManager sharedManager] objectLoaderWithResourcePath:TASKURL delegate:taskGroup];
     [loader sendSynchronously];
     [loader  setTimeoutInterval:60];
     [loader setBackgroundPolicy:RKRequestBackgroundPolicyRequeue];
     [[RKObjectManager sharedManager].requestQueue addRequest:loader];
   }
 } 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a bug in RestKit affecting the combination of synchronous requests and timeouts. Fixed in pull request 553: https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/pull/553